# Android ListView does not display data on app first launch

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

My problem is with android ListView. 
I have designed an android application with fragment. In the fragment there is a ListView, which displays some data. This data is loaded with AsyncTask from the server. When I launch the app the first time ( the app is not even installed on device ), ListView does not display any item. Then, when for example, I minimize the app and maximize it, or switch between app screens the items appeared. I have explored the source code for many hours, but wasn't able to fix the issue. Any help will be highly appreciated. Below is my app code.

The MainActivity.java class.

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements         RateRefreshListener {
    private CurrencyConstants.RATE_TYPES currentTab;

    private int darkColor;
    private int lightColor;

    private String currentCurrency;
    private CurrencyConstants.SORTING currentSorting;

    private RateFragment currentFragment;
    private RateFragment banksFragment;
    private RateFragment exchangesFragment;

    private UserPreferences userPreferences;

    TextView bankOrExchange;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bankOrExchange = ( TextView    )findViewById(R.id.bank_or_exchange);

        userPreferences = UserPreferences.sharedUserPreferences(this);

        darkColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.dark);
        lightColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.light);

        currentTab = CurrencyConstants.RATE_TYPES.EXCHANGE;
        currentCurrency = userPreferences.getCurrencyCode();
        currentSorting = userPreferences.getSortingCode();

        LinearLayout currencyLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.currency);

        for (int index = 0 ; index < currencyLayout.getChildCount() ; index++) {
            TextView currency = (TextView) currencyLayout.getChildAt(index);
            currency.setClickable(true);
            currency.setOnClickListener(currencyClickListener);

            if (userPreferences.getCurrencyCode().equals(CurrencyConstants.CURRENCIES[index])) {
                currency.setBackgroundColor(darkColor);
                currency.setTextColor(lightColor);
            } else {
                currency.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_rect_outlined);
                currency.setTextColor(darkColor);
            }
        }

        LinearLayout sortingLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sorting);

        for (int index = 0 ; index < sortingLayout.getChildCount() ; index++) {
            TextView sorting = (TextView) sortingLayout.getChildAt(index);
            sorting.setClickable(true);
            sorting.setOnClickListener(sortingClickListener);

            if (userPreferences.getSortingCode().equals(CurrencyConstants.SORTING.forIndex(index))) {
                sorting.setBackgroundColor(darkColor);
                sorting.setTextColor(lightColor);
            } else {
                sorting.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_rect_outlined);
                sorting.setTextColor(darkColor);
            }
        }

        showBanks(null);

        APITalker.sharedTalker().refresh(DBTalker.sharedTalker(this), this);
    }


public void showBanks(View view) {

        if (currentTab.equals(CurrencyConstants.RATE_TYPES.BANK)) {
            return;
        }

        currentTab = CurrencyConstants.RATE_TYPES/**/.BANK;

        setupTabs(lightColor, darkColor);

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.from_left_slide_in, R.anim.to_right_slide_out);

        if (banksFragment == null) {
            banksFragment= RateFragment.newInstance(currentCurrency, currentSorting, currentTab);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rate_fragment_container, banksFragment);
        } else {
            banksFragment.setPreferences(currentCurrency, currentSorting);
            bankOrExchange.setText(R.string.bank);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.rate_fragment_container, banksFragment);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        currentFragment = banksFragment;

    }



@Override
    public void rateRefreshSucceed() {
        userPreferences.setLastUpdate(new Date().getTime());
        currentFragment.setPreferences(currentCurrency, currentSorting);
    }

    @Override
    public void rateRefreshFail(String error) {

    }
}
```

The APITalker.java class, which is responsible for interaction with server.

```
public class APITalker {
private final String BASE_URL = "SOME URL";
private final String INDEX_URL = BASE_URL + "/index";

private static APITalker sharedTalker;

private AsyncHttpClient client;

public static APITalker sharedTalker() {
    if (sharedTalker == null) {
        sharedTalker = new APITalker();
    }

    return sharedTalker;
}

private APITalker() {
    client = new AsyncHttpClient();
}

public void refresh(final DBTalker dbTalker, final RateRefreshListener listener) {
    client.get(INDEX_URL, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            dbTalker.store(response);
            listener.rateRefreshSucceed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String       responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString,   throwable);
        }
    });
}
```

The fragment, which contains ListView.

```
package com.flycode.restmobile.fragment;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.flycode.restmobile.R;
import com.flycode.restmobile.activity.MapActivity;
import com.flycode.restmobile.adapter.RateListAdapter;
import com.flycode.restmobile.constant.CurrencyConstants;
import com.flycode.restmobile.database.DBTalker;
import com.flycode.restmobile.model.Rate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RateFragment extends Fragment implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String CURRENCY_CODE = "currencyCode";
    private static final String SORTING_CRITERIA = "sortingCriteria";
    private static final String RATE_TYPE = "rateType";

    private RateListAdapter rateListAdapter;
    private CurrencyConstants.RATE_TYPES rateType;

    public static RateFragment newInstance(String currencyCode, CurrencyConstants.SORTING sortingCriteria, CurrencyConstants.RATE_TYPES rateType) {
        RateFragment fragment = new RateFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(CURRENCY_CODE, currencyCode);
        args.putSerializable(SORTING_CRITERIA, sortingCriteria);
        args.putSerializable(RATE_TYPE, rateType);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public RateFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rate, container, false);

        String currencyCode = getArguments().getString(CURRENCY_CODE);
        CurrencyConstants.SORTING sortingCriteria = (CurrencyConstants.SORTING) getArguments().getSerializable(SORTING_CRITERIA);
        rateType = (CurrencyConstants.RATE_TYPES) getArguments().getSerializable(RATE_TYPE);
        ArrayList<Rate> rates = DBTalker.sharedTalker(getActivity()).getRates(currencyCode, sortingCriteria, rateType);

        rateListAdapter = new RateListAdapter(getActivity(), rates);

        ListView ratesList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.rate_list);
        ratesList.setAdapter(rateListAdapter);
        ratesList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public void setPreferences(String currencyCode, CurrencyConstants.SORTING sortingCriteria) {
        getArguments().putString(CURRENCY_CODE, currencyCode);
        getArguments().putSerializable(SORTING_CRITERIA, sortingCriteria);

        ArrayList<Rate> rates = DBTalker.sharedTalker(getActivity()).getRates(currencyCode, sortingCriteria, rateType);

        rateListAdapter.setRates(rates);
        rateListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    /**
     * OnItemClickListener Methods
     */

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Rate rate = rateListAdapter.getItem(position);

        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
        mapIntent.putExtra(MapActivity.RATE, rate);
        getActivity().startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
}
```

Also my Logcat warning/error output

```
 07-07 13:34:29.357  15256-15256/com.flycode.restmobile E/ION﹕ ION_IOC_CUSTOM_GET_CONFIG ioctl Failed. Use default
07-07 13:34:29.417  15256-15256/com.flycode.restmobile W/JsonHttpResponseHandler﹕ onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback was received
```

Comment: I need your code when you executed the asynctask

Comment: Hi, Sheychan. Thank you for reply. AsyncTask is executed by calling APITalker.sharedTalker().refresh(DBTalker.sharedTalker(this), this); in the last line of onCreate().  The interaction with server is in the APITalker class refresh() function.

Comment: Last thing, I want you to show me warnings/errors on logcat

Comment: Yes, of course, just a moment. :)

Answer (score 1):

First time, when you try to launch the fragment, the data is not present in DB. So you need to refresh the fragment once the data is received.

You are receiving callback for refreshSucceeded in your activity. Form  there you need to call a fragment function to notify the fragment that the data has been changed. Then from that fragment function, you need to refetch data from DBTalker and call notify.

Steps required :

1. Create a function in fragment onDataRefreshed();
2. Call the onDataRefreshed() function from activity onRefreshSucceded() function.
3. Inside onDataRefreshed() function of fragment, do necessary calls to fetch data from DBTalker and reload the list.

Comment: Eldhose M Babu, but I think I do what you say  by calling my fragment's setPreferences function. Or Not?